# How to read .scd data files with in a mfc application

Tags: mfc, exe, extractor, scd

I just purchased and installed a application from 3 Cds using registration key in pendrive. After installation, I just got a MFC Application (.exe). When i viewed the files, I found a data folder inside which I found many .scd files. The data is accessible within the application.

> Now I would like to extract that scd files and need those data alone
>   separately.

I tried with FileViewPro, Scribus and many exe reader Software, but not successful.

Please someone help me to read the .scd files to extract the data from it.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please clarify what is the MFC application you are referring to? Was it installed? How do you know that it is MFC app?

Secondly, by giving just a file extension you do not provide enough information about a file. it could be MD scheduler, MS system management, TurboTax and many more.

The only way to do what you need is to find an application that does that or learn about a file format from documentation and write your own application.

It may be impossible if the file is proprietary format and there is no documentation released.